# JQuery dynamically appending and removing rows in a table

Tags: jquery

I am an intern learning JQuery and was asked to design a basic webpage that shows whether employees are at the office.  Data is displayed in a table in the form of Employee Name, Yes/No buttons(if the employees is in the office), and an optional note about where the employee is.  The user should be able to add and remove employees. I was successfully able to remove employees from the table, but now I am having two issues.

1) I cannot add employees to the table

2) When I added the additional code to add employees, I was no longer able to remove employees from the table.

How do you fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});


$('.sub').click(function() {
    var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var phone = $('input [name=phone]').val();
    var email = $('input [name=email]').val();

    var modal = "<td><button class=\"del\">X</button><a href=\"#openModal\">"+name + " </a><div id=\"openModal\" class=\"modalDialog\"><div><a href=\"#close\" title=\"Close\" class=\"close\">X</a><h2> " + name + "</h2><p>Phone: " + phone + "</p><p>email: " + email + "</p></div></div></td>";
    var radio = "<td> <input type='radio' id='yes'>Yes<br><input type='radio' id='no' >No</td>";
    var textArea = "<td><textarea placeholder='Optional Note about where your are, or your schedule'></textarea></td>";

    var tr = "<tr>" + modal + radio + textArea+ "</tr>";
    $('#table').append(tr);

});
```

});

Comment: please provide a proper fiddle...

Comment: I think you have the "phone" and "email" not right.  It should be "input[name=phone]" and "input[name=email]".  Besides that, you may need to put your code into a jsfiddle example.  I would also suggest using Firefox with the FireBug plugin so you can breakpoint javascript.

Comment: woops haha.  I fixed that, but I am still having the same issues I described earlier

Comment: Your quotes are cancelling eachother out - use single quotes or escape your double quotes

Comment: Ok...I just used the escape characters, which worked, but now the row is added and a second later it is removed.  Sorry for being a pain, but I am new to web design and have spent hours staring at the same thing and its frustrating me.

Comment: Please, read [ask] and [how to create a minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post the most updated code?

Comment: @ovaherenow just edited it.  What is posted should be the most recent code.

Comment: Well it's still wrong

Comment: oh thanks...I didn't know

Comment: @user3771865, Can you create a jsfiddle example?  Also, remove the space after "input".  With the space, it means something totally different.